# script to push and unzip a file in remote server

Tags: shell, ssh, zip

I have datezip.zip and sample.sh script in one server. I am trying to push this datezip.zip file into a target server in particular directory and unzip it there. This process runs inside the sample.sh script

Sample.sh script:

```
#!/bin/ksh
echo "Enter the username" 
read user echo "Enter the IP Address" 
read Ip echo "Enter the directory name" 
read dir 
scp datezip.zip $user@$Ip:$dir/datezip.zip
```

I have pushed the file successfully. but unable to unzip the file.

I tried ssh -t $user@$Ip 'cd $dir; unzip datezip.zip;'

Can anyone please correct me or s there any other way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Got a similar problem a while ago. Solved it by using -n instead of -t with the ssh.

Comment: "I have pushed the file successfully. but unable to unzip the file." What exactly happened when you tried? Did you get an error message? What did it say?

Comment: @Kenster directory name not found error and the session got closed

Comment: thanks all.. I tried the following and got the desired result
ssh  $user@$Ip "unzip $dir/datezip.zip"